# Using Dictionary<T1, T2> in LinQ query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to execute code which looks like:

```
Dictionary<Int64, List<Int64>> types;
// initialization of dictionary
results = (from m in d.Linq() 
           where (filter.Types.Any(x =>
                                 x.Key == m.DocumentType.Code
                                 && x.Value.Contains(m.DocumentPurpose.Code)
                                )
                 )
           select m 
          ).ToList();
```

When I executed this test, I received `System.NullReferenceException`. But I'm sure that object `types` isn't `null` and contains at least one pair (Key: 26; Value: 2, 4).

I think that LINQ can't convert this Any() expression to SQL. How i can rewrite this query?

Comment: Where exactly does it point the `NullReferenceException` to? I see several places it could be, which would have nothing to do with LINQ.

Comment: What is `d`? What is `filter`? Where is `types` used?

Comment: Is this even querying a Database?  If not, it doesn't need to convert it to SQL.

Comment: `d` is an instance of class that extends `NHibernateDAO`.
Problem contains in `Any()` method. I'm sure that `m.DocumentType` and `m.DocumentPurpose` codes is not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
results = (from m in d.Linq() 
           where (m.DocumentType != null &&
                  m.DocumentPurpose != null &&
                  filter.Types.Any(x =>
                                 x.Key == m.DocumentType.Code
                                 && x.Value.Contains(m.DocumentPurpose.Code)
                                )
```